# Using same HttpClient for more than one user/login

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to use same HttpClient for different user, but the user that login platform last(USER_A for example) modifies the HttpClient. JSessionId, token all of them changes to the USER_A. So when i hit a url/api using different user(USER_B) on a different server, it sees me as the last user i.e. USER_A.

So, my question is how can i reuse HttpClient for more than one user logged in at same time. First i thought of using a map<jsessionid,HttpClient> but then i read creating Httpclient again and again is costly.
Is there any approach where i can reuse the same HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

SessionId will be mostly created and stored on Browser with a specific expiry date, now if you we try with same browser before the token expires then we might possibly get the same error, which you are facing now, try using different browsers so that you can generate multiple Tokens and have different sessionId for multiple logged in users

Comment: Yes i am logging in on different browser with different user, and yes i get different jsession id but as I’ve written in my question who ever loggins last modifies the http client.